# What are the default IE select box styles?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a select box styled for good browsers, and for ie9 and down, I wish to have the default select box displayed, with no custom styles.

Styles for good browsers:

```
select {
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
/*ie-10 fix*/
select.select-k::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
select.select-k {
    font-family: Bitter, Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
select.select-k.quantity {
    width: 80px;
    background: url(../img/forms/arrow.png) no-repeat 80% 50% #fff;
}
```

Now I have the following conditional:

```
  <!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bugbrowser.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

My question is, in order to overwrite those styles on IE, should I redeclare all values? If so, where can I see the default IE styles to overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that IE 10 and higher don't support conditional comments, why not write something like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Or if you persist on using inline styles:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <style>
        select {
            display: inline-block;
            background: transparent;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.3;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            height: 40px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
        }
        /*ie-10 fix*/
        select.select-k::-ms-expand {
            display: none;
        }
        select.select-k {
            font-family: Bitter, Georgia, serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            border: none;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        select.select-k.quantity {
            width: 80px;
            background: url(../img/forms/arrow.png) no-repeat 80% 50% #fff;
        }
    </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

---

So let's say you create a new file that you only want to display on modern browsers, (including IE10+, but not IE9 and below) then you'd call that file something like: `gt-ie9.css` (*greater than IE 9*). Then, in your HTML you'd call that CSS like so:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path-to-file/gt-ie9.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: If I do that, I presume I will have NO styles on IE. Or am I wrong? The point here to have ALL the styles but the ones related with the select box. Those, should stay the browser defaults on IE.

Comment: So, I should remove those styles on my main.css file, and place it inside another CSS file. Is that it?

Comment: @MEM What do you mean exactly? Your styles for "good browsers" won't be used. Instead, the browser will use its default styles for the select options. That's what you wanted, right? Not "no" styles, but the browser's default styles.

Comment: @MEM That would be prettiest, yeah. However, see my second approach. You could also add the styles as HTML.

Comment: to absolutely clear my doubts, let's say I would go with the prettiest solution. I would then call my css file: "only-for-good-browsers.css" because, that's what I'm doing. Correct? I will have, on a css the styles that work for all BUT ie browsers.